# What is the reasoning behind the solution of the determinant of this matrix? What rules were used here?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I can't figure out how this determinant was calculated. I tried using Sarrus' rule but ended up with a complicated expression.

Why do I make all the elements in my first column to 
$1+\omega +{\omega}^2$ ?

How do I get my answer as $0$ ?

[image]

Comment: By elementary operations on the columns as explained in the solution $c_1' = c_1+c_2+c_3$.

Answer (score 1):

The second and third columns were added to the first column.  I guess that $\omega$ is the cube-root of $1$, so that makes the first column entries all $0$, which makes it easy to see that the determinant is $0$.

Comment: Why are the second and third columns added to the first column? Why doesn't adding change the determinant?

Comment: As $1+\omega +{\omega}^2=0$,  he made it so . Making a whole column $0$ would extremely simplify the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

1, $\omega$ and $\omega ^2$ are the cube roots of unity. Sum of cube roots of unity is 0. So the determinant is 0